# wordpress pre-defined format post

Tags: wordpress

I want to use wordpress post to store product information in a pre-defined format. For example post #1 stores the following content (the post_content field of table _post):

```
<product>
    <name>cup</name>
    <color>red</color>
    <price>$2.5</price>
</product>
```

So I need to create my own "New Post" back-end interface (a plugin?) in wp-admin. And this interface provide

1. a html form for user to specify the name, color, price of a product.
2. generate post content with information from 1.
3. post the content to wordpress database when click on submit.

The problem is that I have no clue how to do it in wordpress. Could anyone share any tutorials or information to me?

P.S. I have knowledge of html+js+css+php, but a starter with wordpress.

Comment: the default new post interface of wordpress is only good for writing an article, but not for a strictly defined format content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store the information exactly in wp_posts.content field, you can look at add_meta_box() function. Here is a tutorial for it https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes--wp-20336

Then you will be able to handle the values when saving post, and generate the post content. This should be done on `save_post` hook that is described in the tutorial as well, something like

`add_action( 'save_post', 'name_of_the_function_generating_xml' );`

If it's ok for you to store the values separately in wp_postmeta table, then maybe https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ plugin is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks c0der, I will look at the information you provided. And, no, writing into post content field is not a exact requirement, any wordpress solution will do.

Comment: I tried the add_meta_box way. This is exactly what I want. Thanks very much!